# Is it possible to get an Accept hosted page where the credit card entry field is masked?

Tags: authorize.net

Is it possible to get an Accept hosted page where the credit card entry field is masked? So for example if we had the form running on a kiosk a criminal couldn't stand behind them and take a picture of the form?

Checked documentation here: https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/accept-hosted.html
Nothing appears to do this....